# Inverse function of y=10^x

Tags: inverse-function

How do I find the inverse function of $y=f(x)=10^x$? As per my knowledge I have to swap $x$ for $y$. In that case it'll be $x=10^y$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ f(x)=y=10^x $$

you are correct in finding the [inverse of a function by swapping the variables](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/invrsfcn3.htm), so

$$ \begin{align*}
&f^{-1}(x) = x = 10^y \\
&f^{-1}(x) = y = \log_{10}(x) \quad (1)
\end{align*}$$

where $ f^{-1}(x) $ is the inverse of $f(x)$

> $(1)$ This step uses [the property of logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) that $x=b^y \implies y=\log_b(a)$

Comment: I didn't get the 3rd step. Why did you add Log x? Why you again swap x and y?

Comment: One last thing, may be silly. As author again swap x and y after in example of http://www.purplemath.com/modules/invrsfcn3.htm. Do I need to swap them again after step 2? That's where my main confusion is.

Comment: @gmailuser You only need to swap once and then solve for $y$. This is, however, not the same equation as you started with, it is the inverse.